# Freeing the zSql arg to sqlite3_prepare_v2?

Tags: c, sqlite, free

If I have a dynamically allocated string containing the query I am passing to sqlite3_prepare_v2(), when is it safe to free this string?  Immediately after sqlite3_prepare_v2()?  After sqlite3_step is DONE?  Not until after sqlite3_finalize()?  Does the value of the nByte parameter affect the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html):

> The sqlite3_prepare_v2() and sqlite3_prepare16_v2() interfaces are
>   recommended for all new programs. The two older interfaces are
>   retained for backwards compatibility, but their use is discouraged. In
>   the "v2" interfaces, the prepared statement that is returned (the
>   sqlite3_stmt object) **contains a copy** of the original SQL text.

I believe that this means that you can safely free or modify the string right after calling `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`.

**EDIT:**

A short jaunt along the `sqlite3.c` code reveals this little snippet:

```
SQLITE_PRIVATE void sqlite3VdbeSetSql(Vdbe *p, const char *z, int n, int isPrepareV2){
  assert( isPrepareV2==1 || isPrepareV2==0 );
  if( p==0 ) return;
#ifdef SQLITE_OMIT_TRACE
  if( !isPrepareV2 ) return;
#endif
  assert( p->zSql==0 );
  p->zSql = sqlite3DbStrNDup(p->db, z, n);
  p->isPrepareV2 = (u8)isPrepareV2;
}
```

Basically, if this is called by `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`, a version of `strndup()` is called to create a copy of the string...

Comment: I was concerned by these words in the docs "_passing an nByte parameter that is equal to the number of bytes in the input string including the nul-terminator bytes as this saves SQLite from having to make a copy of the input string_", but I guess that is an unrelated copy.